# Ember.js: Dynamically changing the 'class' of an Ember object via prototype and meta

Tags: javascript, ember.js, metaprogramming, prototype

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the 'class' (derived from `Ember.Object.extend`) of an existing object instance, such that computed properties, Ember's `_super` / inheritance / mixins, bindings, observers, and all the other benefits of the Ember Object model still work.

I've tried simply setting the `__proto__` to a different class's `prototype`, but this fails for computed properties (it will look up the the old class's computed properties):

```
Triangle = Ember.Object.extend
  sides: 3
  greeting: (->
    "I'm a triangle and I have #{sides} sides"
  ).property('sides')

Square = Ember.Object.extend
  sides: 4
  greeting: (->
    "I'm a square and I have #{sides} sides"
  ).property('sides')

t = Triangle.create()
t.get('greeting') # I'm a triangle and I have 3 sides
t.__proto__ = Square.prototype
t.get('greeting') # I'm a triangle and I have 3 sies
```

In looking through the source, it seems that `Ember.get` resolves computed properties via the `meta` object (source: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.1.2/packages/ember-metal/lib/property_get.js#L66). I can see a list of all the properties by poking around the meta object `t[Ember.META_KEY].desc`, but I'm unclear exactly what to do with the meta object.

How can I modify the meta object to allow computed properties and bindings to work with the newly reassigned prototype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer is you shouldn't do this. Ember sets up a lot under the hood and trying to manually rip out the guts and re-build them is definitely not recommended.

I'm sure there is a better solution for this, like copying the properties over to a new instance of your object.

Or if you are using Ember Data maybe Polymorphic relationships can be used.

Comment: Yeah I'm really pushing ember here, haha. I have a very good reason for doing this however -- arbitrarily nested polymorphic types that need to be bindable to a template. It's like a JSON editor, but with user-definable complex types. Since editing a particular node in the tree can change that node's type, I want to be able to change the corresponding class.